# View 404 response code not visible in Python test

Tags: python, testing, http-status-code-404, urllib3

I've created a test for my Python code where I do a PATCH operation using a non existant bucket. I expect a 404 response but instead get this:

```
HTTPSConnectionPool(host='config.storage.cloud.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /v1/foo (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x10ffe8c90>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 8] nodename nor servname provided, or not known',))
```

The response kinda makes sense but is there any way I can view the response code? I assume if there is it will be through urllib3 in some way.

Answer (score 0):

There is no response code. The actual error messages is towards the end:

```
[Errno 8] nodename nor servname provided, or not known
```

This generally means that your system was not able to resolve a DNS record for the domain name. If you check the DNS on that domain name you will see that it does not have an A record. Hence, you never get a response code because your request cannot even route to the server. Maybe if you would like to give us more context around what you are trying to test we can help with a better approach.